# Set ARM64 register to -1

Tags: assembly, arm

I'm learning asm and here is my problem

```
bl         method_which_returns_number
mov        x21, x0
cmp        w21, #0x1
```

It seems that method called by bl will return number to register x21, is it correct?
How can i modify/set either x21 or x0 register to integer -1 ?

Comment: Can't you do something like this: `mov x21 #~0x0`?

Comment: Does ~0x0 means -1?

Comment: Yes, in 2s complements, if I am not mistaken ARM uses 2s complements

Comment: I have added the answer that works for sure.

Comment: Do you have some more code, something is missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 mov  x0, #-1
```

assembles like this: (with `aarch64-linux-gnu-as minus1.S` && `aarch64-linux-gnu-objdump -d a.out`):

```
0:   92800000        mov     x0, #0xffffffffffffffff         // #-1
```

This is `movn x0, #0`

---

ARM assemblers know how to encode `mov` various ways to support different kinds of immediate bit-patterns.  AArch64 has several forms of immediates with different encoding rules.  **Using `mov` will give an error if it can't assemble to a single instruction with immediate**, so you don't have to worry about it turning into a PC-relative load like the ARM32 `ldr r0, =constant` pseudo-instruction can.

The ARM documentation lists several forms of `mov`, and [one of them is an alias for `movn`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0802b/MOV_MOVN.html), which negates its source operand.  Other forms include one based on `orr`-immediate (with an architectural zero register) that supports a repeated bit-pattern 2,4,8,16,32, or 64 bits wide.  And one based on `movz`, a 16-bit immediate left-shifted to any position.

---

> It seems that method called by bl will return number to register x21, is it correct?

No, ARM syntax is `op  dst, src`.

`mov x21, x0` is copying the return value from `x0` to `x21`.  Integer return values are in `x/w0`, just like in AArch32 where return values are in `r0`.

Comment: tried `00 00 80 92` and it shows `mov x0, #0xffffffffffffffff // #-1` on https://onlinedisassembler.com/odaweb/ but `MOVN X0, #0` on http://armconverter.com/hextoarm/